# Use cookie value in request header

Tags: paw-app

For the request I need to make I have to pass the CSRF token as the `X-CSRFTOKEN` header, the value of this header needs to be the value of a cookie set from the cookiejar.  How can I have only the cookie value for a specific cookie as a variable?